# Cannot center div properly. Margin: 0 auto; not working

Tags: html, css

I want a fixed, full-height side bar and main content centered in the remaining space to the right of said sidebar.

I  am close, but the main content does not properly center in the wrapper div when using ***Margin: 0 auto;***. The left margin of #content is significantly larger than the left.

**Please help me center the main content div in the wrapper div.**

[See JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ytbgcrc/)

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<body > 

    <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p> this is the sidebar, it's ok as it is</p>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content"> 
            <ul>
            This div needs to be cetnered in the #wrapper with auto margins.
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was simple. I changed the #wrapper width:100% to **max-width:100%**.

[See the fixed fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ytbgcrc/2/)

**Updated CSS**

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  **max-width: 100%;**
}

#content {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```